# How to transform an Application.Transpose with a pastespecial to put only value and not format?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim ar as variable

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(UBound(ar) + 1) = 
Application.Transpose(ar)
```

It work perfectly except it paste the format. I have strange number in my list and it should be paste as text because excel convert those number into date or different value.

How to add the following with the Application.Transpose?
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Edit2: Below code should sort value in column B of sheet2 and transpose them in Sheet1. However, it does not transpose value. I did something wrong?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
DoEvents

Dim r As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ar As Variant
Dim var As Variant

With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").CurrentRegion
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each rng In Range("B3", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
var = .Item(rng.Value)
Next
ar = .Keys
End With
End With
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(UBound(ar) + 1)
.NumberFormat = "@"
.Value = Application.Transpose(ar)
End With
```

Comment: Now that you have posted additional code, see my Edit'd answer for an explanation of what is going wrong with your code, and a proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you show is not pasting any formats at all (assuming `ar` is a variant containing values, and not an array of cell ranges).

Try (not tested):

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(UBound(ar) + 1)
    .numberformat = "@"
    .value = Application.Transpose (ar)
end with
```

#### Edit:

Now that you have posted additional code, showing how you populated `ar`, it is more clear what is going on.

```
ar = .Keys
```

produces a one dimensional array.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(UBound(ar) + 1)
```

returns a vertical cell range.

And your source region:

```
Range("B3", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

is also a vertical region.

You need to understand about passing arrays between VBA and the worksheets.  If the link is still live, a  good explanation is Chip Pearson's [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Your one dimensional VBA array should go to a horizontal worksheet range.  To fill a vertical worksheet range, you'd need a 2D array.

And your destination range needs to be created as a horizontal range; you have created it as a vertical range.

So the relevant part of your code, with some editing for robustness, and indenting for readability, would read:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ar As Variant
Dim var As Variant

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set r = .Range("B3", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With


With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each rng In r
        var = .Item(rng.Value)
    Next
    ar = .Keys
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(columnsize:=UBound(ar) + 1)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = ar
End With

End Sub
```

This will paste a vertical range of data from `Sheet2!B3:Bn` into a horizontal range starting at `Sheet1!A4`.  Which is what I think you want.

**Edit 2:**

Unless you are going to have some other reason for using the Dictionary object, a shorter, equivalent version of the code would be:

```
  Dim ar As Variant
  Dim var As Variant

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    ar = .Range("B3", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(columnsize:=UBound(ar))
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ar)
End With
```

Note that, in this case,

- we fill our VBA array in a single step
- in sizing the destination range, we do **NOT** add the `+1`
- we **DO** transpose the array before writing it to the destination

If you read through the reference above, you should be able to work out the logic of these changes.

Answer (score 0):

And what would be the change to make this code paste vertical instead of horizontal? By changing the ColumnSize by RowSize the value is pasted vertically but it does not sort all value. IE 1,2,3,4,5 it will only paste 1,1,1,1,1

```
Dim r As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ar As Variant
Dim var As Variant

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
  Set r = .Range("B3", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With


With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each rng In r
        var = .Item(rng.Value)
    Next
    ar = .Keys
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(RowSize:=UBound(ar) + 1)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = ar
End With

End Sub
```